# Unable to boot with kernel panic after updating on MacPro (Early 2008)?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel

I installed some updates to Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS Xenial today, and when my MacPro (Early 2008) rebooted, I was welcomed by a kernel panic and a message reading:

```
VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)
```

I was then able to boot into GRUB2 and after selecting from the advanced options a few times, I was able to boot the machine again using the `4.4.0-53-generic` version of the kernel.

Upon booting I received a crash report about the `linux-firmware 1.157.6` package and that the error message was `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1`

Is there some reason for this?  Is there anything I should read or do to keep my machine working?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that two things were wrong:

1. My /boot was 95% full and it could not continue with the upgrade.
2. There was a PPA screwing it up, and I removed it from /etc/apt/sources.d/

[After that I cleaned up my linux-images, and ran apt-get autoremove](http://www.technovechno.com/2016/01/how-to-clean-boot-on-ubuntu.html)

It now seems to be working correctly again.